# What's the good way to get messages from a specific facebook wall?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-wall

There is a groupwall of which I want to download and store all messages in a db.
In the documentation I cannot find a good way to do it. Did I miss something? What's the good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Graph API to get wall posts, it returns items in a nice JSON format.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be really surprised if they weren't available as an rss or atom feed for downloading. (It's not using the API, but is probably the cheapest way.)

Comment: Probably there is an rss for that, but i couln't find any. At least not one with the messages. There is one with "you got a wall message" though.

Comment: That you got a wall message should be a feed of all wall messages. Have a look at it.

Comment: groups don't have the you got a wall message stuff either, a really can't find feed for the group wall :/